# Как защищается gitlab-ee?

Tags: gitlab

У гитлаба есть две версии, CE - бесплатная, EE - платная, но обе имеют открытый исходный код. Таким образом, что мешает мне пользоваться EE версией бесплатно?

Comment: нарушение лицензионного соглашения может привести к штрафу

Comment: Технически — ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но обе имеют открытый исходный код.

Нет, [открытым](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) является только код CE. Лицензия Gitlab EE защищает код не только (и не столько) от воровства, но и от распространения другими разработчиками.

Gitlab CE использует разрешительную [лицензию MIT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_MIT). Это значит, что Вы имеете право использовать код Gitlab CE в своем продукте, при этом развивать и распространять его под своей лицензией.

Код EE-версии доступен для просмотра и изучения, но Вы не имеете права использовать его в своих продуктах, распространять его самостоятельно.

В такой модели (см. «[open core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_core)») предоставить доступ к коду EE — внутреннее бизнес-решение «Gitlab, Inc», обусловленное целевой аудиторией: разработчиками. Разработчики, во-первых, будут рады изучить код, во-вторых, могут помочь с обнаружением и исправлением ошибок. В то же время лицензия не позволит им написать свой вариант EE.

> ... что мешает мне пользоваться EE версией бесплатно?

Скорее всего этому мешает законодательство страны в которой Вы находитесь, ибо [лицензия Gitlab EE](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/blob/master/LICENSE) недвусмысленно устанавливает, что пользоваться продуктом без подписки нельзя. Закон так же определяет степень ответственности за неправомерное использование программных продуктов и меры по выявлению подобных нарушений.

Вопросы вроде «Насколько вероятно привлечение к ответственности именно за Gitlab EE?» и «Какова степень ответственности за нелицензионное ПО?» выходят за рамки моей компетенции и тематики Stackoverflow (статьи по общей теме на Хабре: [1](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207356/), [2](https://habrahabr.ru/company/itarena/blog/118686/), [3](https://habrahabr.ru/post/57892/), [4](https://geektimes.ru/post/182848/)). Советую по этим вопросам получить консультацию у квалифицированного юриста.

Answer (score 0):

Касательно технической части вопроса: при установке GitLab-EE пользователь получает версию с закрытыми фичами от EE. На главной странице можно ввести код продукта, то есть нельзя пользоваться EE версией бесплатно даже технически.

Comment: Вопрос как раз о том, что код открыт и проверку ключа, технически, можно выбросить.